# Using a path-based filter with Restangular Object

Tags: angularjs, restangular

So I have a project with two api calls as such:

GET /certificates/pending - returns all of the pending certificates
POST /certificates//approve (or deny) - approves the certificate.

The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure how to add the /pending to the getList() command, but not to the object itself, so Restangular tries to POST to /certificates/pending//approve, which isn't a valid path.

```
 angular.module( 'approvals', [
      'ui.router'
     ])

    .config(function config( $stateProvider, RestangularProvider ) {
  $stateProvider.state( 'system.approvals', {
    url: '/approvals',
        controller: 'ApprovalsCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'approvals/approvals.tpl.html',
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Approvals' },
    authenticate: true,
    resolve:{
      certificates: function(Certificates){
        return Certificates.all('pending').getList();
      }
    }
  });
})

.factory('Certificates', function(Restangular){
  return Restangular.service('certificates');
})
;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this..

```
angular.module( 'approvals', [
      'ui.router'
     ])

    .config(function config( $stateProvider, RestangularProvider ) {
  $stateProvider.state( 'system.approvals', {
    url: '/approvals',
        controller: 'ApprovalsCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'approvals/approvals.tpl.html',
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Approvals' },
    authenticate: true,
    resolve:{
      certificates: function(Certificates){
            return Restangular.allUrl('certificates', 'http://apiURL/certificates/pending').getList();
      }
    }
  });
})
;`
```

It's not optimal, as I now have to manage the apiURL in two places, but at least it works.